# Adding JTextArea to JFrame

Tags: swing, jframe, jpanel, awt, jtextarea

If I have 1 main class and 2 subclasses

- subclass 1: public class JPanel1 extends JPanel {....properly initialized}
- subclass 2: public class JTextArea1 extends JTextArea {... properly initialized}

Why can I do jframe1.add(new JPanel1()) but not jframe1.add(new JTextArea1())? for a properly initialized JFrame jframe1 = new JFrame();?

My goal is to output data into both the jpanel and the jtextarea

Comment: Exactly why you need to inherit these two classes to do the job ? Why composition alone isn't enough ? You need to ask these questions first before proceeding... :-) Though, only one component can be added at any given location, if you hadn't changed the layout for the `JFrame`, which is `BorderLayout`. In this case both are added to the `CENTER` position.

Comment: Moreover, had you tried to override the [__getPreferredSize()__](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getPreferredSize()) for both the components inside the inherited classes ? If not then do so, and make them return some genuine Dimension object `like return (new Dimension(300, 300))`.

Comment: Compose JPanel and JTextArea into one class?. I have them added such that jpanel is at layout.center and the jtextarea is at layout.east

Comment: Please do have a look at the answer, I hope this clears the doubts :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here on my side, the issue you raising, is working fine. Do let me know, if you think, this is not what you mean :-)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingExample
{
    private CustomPanel customPanel;
    private CustomTextArea customTextArea;

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        contentPane.setBorder(
                BorderFactory.createLineBorder(
                                Color.DARK_GRAY, 5));
        customPanel = new CustomPanel();
        customTextArea = new CustomTextArea();

        contentPane.add(customPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPane.add(customTextArea, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);      
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new SwingExample().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}

class CustomPanel extends JPanel
{
    private static final int GAP = 5;

    public CustomPanel()
    {
        setOpaque(true);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(
                Color.BLUE, GAP, true));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return (new Dimension(300, 300));
    }
}

class CustomTextArea extends JTextArea
{
    private static final int GAP = 5;
    public CustomTextArea()
    {       
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(
                Color.RED, GAP, true));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return (new Dimension(100, 30));
    }
}
```

### OUTPUT :

[image: SwingExampleImage]

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't overriding the dimensions. setPreferredSize wasn't working for me.

Comment: You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)